# Mapping - Mongodb Embedded Document in Symfony2

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am trying to add a mapping information in Symfony2 using MongoDB as shown here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html [at the Adding Information section]
But what I want to do is to add an embedded documents as well.
Here is a part of my document with embedded documents :

```
"_id" : "",
"last_name" :,
"first_name" : "",
"address" : [
{
    "Street" : "",
    "City" : "",
    "Zip_Code" : "",
    "Country": ""

}
],
"company" : ""
"purshaed_items" : [
{
    "items_id" : "",
    "category":"",
    "price":"",
    "date_of_purshae"

}
]
```

So as you can see I have the fields "Address" & "Purshaed_items" that are embedded documents.
I found this link http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/embedded-mapping.html
I guess that my case will be the "Embed Many" but didn't really get how it works?

Can someone please try to explain how it works?

Thank you

Comment: "Address" & "Purshaed_items" are arrays

Comment: And..? how should this be handled for mapping?

Comment: Is it something like that? http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/introduction.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make it like this:

```
/** @EmbedMany(targetDocument="PurshaedItem") */
    private $purshaedItems = array();
```

Assuming that you have another document class named PurshaedItem (PurchasedItem perhaps).

And the target document would be mapped like this:

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\EmbeddedDocument
 */
class PurchasedItem
{
  // whatever properties ...
}
```

And if you want to query for embedded documents, you can get it in controller (recommended), here is my simple [example](https://github.com/djuro/sfmdbBlog/blob/master/Controller/ShowController.php#L62).

For getting it in twig template, here is another [example](https://github.com/djuro/sfmdbBlog/blob/master/Resources/views/Post/list.html.twig#L18).

The examples are from simple Symfony blog application. There are 3 documents: Post, Tag, and Comment. Post has Tags and Comments as embedded properties. Take a look around the code, it is simple.
If the answer has been useful to you, please click to accept it.

Comment: Alright, will test that tonight and let you know. thank you very much ;)

Comment: Mhhh I am facing another issue...I am trying to guery that embedded document to display information on the twig view, but can only get the parent document, any idea how I get the Address information please? I tried that : `Public function GuestAction()
    {
        $customer= $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager')            
                ->getRepository('TestBundle:cutomer')
                ->findAll();
        
    
        return $this->render('TestBundle:Default:test.html.twig', array('customer' => array('purshaedItems' => 'purshaedItems' ))) ;
    }`

Comment: Anyone please? I'm really stuck for more than 24 hours trying to get it workings :/