# Quyery Embedded Document Mongodb Doctrine

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I spent more than 24 hours to get a solution to my issue :
I have mapped embedded document in mongodb document, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33822297/mapping-mongodb-embedded-document-in-symfony2/33825798#33825798)
And now I am trying to return information to the view. here is the main document :

```
/**
* Myproject\MyprojectBundle\Document\guest
*/
class guest
{

/**
 * @var $guest_id
 */
protected $guest_id;

/**
 * @var string $last_name
 */
protected $last_name;

/**
 * @var string $first_name
 */
protected $first_name;

/**
 * @var string $gender
 */
protected $gender;

/**
 * @var string $title
 */
protected $title;

/**
 * @var float $telephone
 */
protected $telephone;

/**
 * @var string $mail
 */
protected $mail;

/**
 * @var string $language
 */
protected $language;

/**
 * @var date $birthday
 */
protected $birthday;

/**
 * @var string $status
 */
protected $status;

/**
 * @var string $company
 */
protected $company;

/**
 * @var Pms\PmsBundle\Document\address
 */
protected $address = array();
```

And here is my address document :

```
<?php

namespace Pms\PmsBundle\Document;



/**
* Myproject\MyprojectBundle\Document\address
*/
class address
{
/**
 * @var string $street
 */
protected $street;

/**
 * @var string $city
 */
protected $city;

/**
 * @var string $zip_code
 */
protected $zip_code;

/**
 * @var string $country
 */
protected $country;


/**
 * Set street
 *
 * @param string $street
 * @return self
 */
public function setStreet($street)
{
    $this->street = $street;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get street
 *
 * @return string $street
 */
public function getStreet()
{
    return $this->street;
}

/**
 * Set city
 *
 * @param string $city
 * @return self
 */
public function setCity($city)
{
    $this->city = $city;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get city
 *
 * @return string $city
 */
public function getCity()
{
    return $this->city;
}

/**
 * Set zipCode
 *
 * @param string $zipCode
 * @return self
 */
public function setZipCode($zipCode)
{
    $this->zip_code = $zipCode;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get zipCode
 *
 * @return string $zipCode
 */
public function getZipCode()
{
    return $this->zip_code;
}

/**
 * Set country
 *
 * @param string $country
 * @return self
 */
public function setCountry($country)
{
    $this->country = $country;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get country
 *
 * @return string $country
 */
public function getCountry()
{
    return $this->country;
}
}
```

At the moment I am only able to return the guest document from my controller :

```
Public function GuestAction()
{
    $guest = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
                   ->getRepository('MyProjectBundle:guest')
                   ->findAll();

return $this->render('MyProjectBundle:Default:guest.html.twig', array('guest' => $guest)) ;
}
```

But not the embedded one, could someone tell me what is wrong please? Or maybe give me a link to any website or something like that.

Comment: Are you justified in using the Embedded doc approach and not the Reference approach ?

Comment: Yea I read in the Mongo Document that it is better to use embedded approach when it is possible, and in my case, the embedded approach is better.

Comment: What I want to do is to return that address field, but it is an array field...do you know how I can do that?

Comment: Nobody can help me please?

Answer (score 0):

With the use of MongoDB annotations

```
 /**
 * @MongoDB\EmbedMany(
 *  strategy="set",
 *  targetDocument="Address",
 * )
 */
protected $address;
public function __construct()
{
    $this->address = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

Then for Address Document :

```
/**
  * @MongoDB\Document(collection="address",repositoryClass="AppBundle\Document\AddressRepository")
 * )
 */
class Address { ... }
```